# How to get JavaScript to match a regex containing variables and spanning multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, variables, newline

How to get JavaScript to match a regex containing variables and spanning multiple lines?

I am trying to extract string data from a body of text by matching patterns where I know the strings being searched for start and end with certain strings which I pass to the routine. The following line is the heart of the routine:

```
var aHits = strIn.match(new RegExp(preStr + "(.+?)" + postStr, ignoreCase + "g"));
// ignoreCase equals "i" or "", preStr is leading string, postStr is trailing
```

This works well until the would-be match contains a line break. Then strIn.match() fails.

I've tried using `"(.+?)"`, `"([\\\s\\\S])"` and `"((.|\\\n|\\\r)+?)"` and several other grouping strategies.

I've seen some literal regexes that end with "s" for doing something like this. Can the variables be added to a literal regex? Which pattern is the best, or at least works? Or is it the match method itself that refuses to process a string with newlines? I can't seem to find that stated anywhere.

The newline is contained in the `(.+?)` portion of the matched string, but would it matter anyway?

Comment: Jeff, I just realized that, while `[\\s\\S]` is _more_ correct, that must not be the problem you're having.  Because the string `[\\\s\\\S]` will evaluate to `[\\s\\S]` (escaped characters are processed from left to right, so the double backslash is replaced with a single backslash, and unrecognized escape sequences, like `\s` will simply be replaced by the character following the backslash).  But I've tried your regex, and it works as expected, so I think you need to post some sample input that is failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there...the dot metacharacter doesn't match newlines, but you were on the right track with `[\\\s\\\S]`...you just escaped one too many times.  Try this:

```
var aHits = strIn.match(
    new RegExp(preStr + "([\\s\\S]+?)" + postStr, ignoreCase + "g"));
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought I had to put those bs chars in to get the doubles to show up. Funny thing, though, I pasted in your code directly into mine and I get the same results. I am running it against an invoice header string with lots of newlines. I am running 4 tests. 3 work flawlessly but do not contain any newlines in the matched string. The 4th test contains newlines in the matched string and returns aHits as null. Is there something here that javascript just doesn't want to do?

Comment: See my comment against your question; you're right, the problem is not the escaping, but both your regex and my answer "work" for me, in that they're consuming newlines as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ethan. I'll just have to go back and look at the strings again. Maybe it's something with them. I do use one with a dot "." but it is the preStr for an instance that works and the postStr for the one that doesn't.

Comment: Just an update, I put the following code in before calling the regex routine:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know hitting enter would do that. Anyway, I put the following code in before calling the regex routine: `text = text.replace(/[\n\r\t\v\f]/g," ");` The "\n" newlines were just fine, it was "\r" carriage returns that turned out to be a problem. I don't know if "[\s\S]" is supposed to handle this, but this javascript is running on a server via the Nashorn script engine which is supposed to be ecmascript compliant. Thanks, it would have been very difficult to find if you guys hadn't first verified that the regex was valid.